# Find elements with a specific tag/attribute pattern

Tags: javascript

In the pages there may happen clickable telephones:

```
<a href="tel:375292995978">: +375 (29) 339-59-78</a>
<a href="tel:: +375 (29) 339-59-78">
```

I'd like to assign an event listener to all telephones.
The only clearly recogizable pattern here is `a href="tel`.

Anything else may change: the number, the icon etc.

How can I find all these elements using JavaScript?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The selector `a[href^='tel:']` should do the trick.

Comment: All the selectors are [documented](//drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#overview).

Answer (score 4):

using querySelectorAll:

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll("a[href^=tel]"));
```

```html
<a href="tel:375292995978">: +375 (29) 339-59-78</a>
<a href="tel:: +375 (29) 339-59-78">
```

[REFERENCE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Attribute_selectors#substring_matching_selectors) (ref: matt123miller comment)

Comment: This is correct but more importantly the reason why this is correct can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Attribute_selectors#substring_matching_selectors

Comment: reference added.